# How to group and order json values in jquery 'each' loop

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to pull the data from the json below for US Reps and Senators into a dropdown menu... ideally grouped by "Sen" and "Rep" and then alphabetized.  So far, the code below is working to get all of the members into the dropdown, but not grouped or alphabetized.  Would love any ideas, thank you!

```
<script>


$.ajax({
url:'https://theunitedstates.io/congress-legislators/legislators- 
current.json',
dataType: 'json',
type:'get',
cache:false,
success:function(data) {
$(data).each(function(index, value) {

     $("#members").append("<option>" + value.terms[value.terms.length- 
1].type + " " + value.name.first + " " + value.name.last + "</option>");
    });
}

});



</script>

<form>

    <select id="members" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
        <option selected="selected">Select...</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTML `<optgroup>` element creates a grouping of options within a `<select>` element.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

```
    <select id="members" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
        <optgroup id="senators" label="Senators"></optgroup>
        <optgroup id="reps" label="US Reps"></optgroup>
    </select>
```

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

---

So, if you'd like to sort by last name, you can try this:

```
    var reps = [];
    var senators = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://theunitedstates.io/congress-legislators/legislators-current.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $(data).each(function (index, value) {

                if (value.terms[value.terms.length - 1].type == 'sen') {
                    // add to senators
                    senators.push(value.name.last + ', ' + value.name.first);
                } else {
                    // add to reps
                    reps.push(value.name.last + ', ' + value.name.first)
                }

            });

            senators.sort();
            reps.sort();

            senators.forEach(function (val) {
                $("#senators").append("<option>" + "SEN. " + " " + val + "</option>");
            });

            reps.forEach(function (val) {
                $("#reps").append("<option>" + "REP. " + val  + "</option>");
            })

        }

    });
```

---

***JSFiddle:*** (https://jsfiddle.net/eb1ayera/)

Comment: Beat me to it! Small detail: instead of populating new arrays and sorting them afterwards, you can sort the whole `data` array once and then insert into the appropriate option group